# jQuery: find H2 id and append link with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and I want for every `H2` with `id` attribute I would create an anchor link. I can not get it to work properly...

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <h2 id="first">first</h2>
    <h2>second</h2>
    <h2 id="third">third</h2>
</div>

.sls {color: red;font-size: 12px;}

$('#mydiv')
.find('h2[id]')
.append(' <a href="http://www.test.com/page.html#'+ $('h2[id]')
.attr('id') +'" class="sls">Link</a>');
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/ivanionut/1ohh2hws/**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```js
$('#mydiv').find('h2[id]').each(function () {
  $(this).append(' <a href="http://www.test.com/page.html#'+ $(this).attr('id') +'" class="sls">Link</a>');
});
```

```css
.sls {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
 <h2 id="first">first</h2>
 <h2>second</h2>
 <h2 id="third">third</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Now I understand .. I would have to use a .each() function. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In your append call you are using $('h2[id]).attr() this will get the attribute of the first element in the set found, so it will always get the id for the first h2. Update the code to use **this** in the append using a function, like so:

```
.append(function() {
    return '<a href="http://www.test.com/page.html#'+ $(this).attr('id') +'"class="sls">Link</a>'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ohh2hws/2/